# Prevent my ::after from blocking my select

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Here is a fiddle demonstrating my problem: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yrkwteuv/)

I'm making a custom drop down (in reality I'm using an icomoon icon instead of the V)... it looks nice, but the `::after` for the parent element is blocking the select :(

```
<div class="select-style">
  <select>
    <option value="">...</option>
    <option value="1365">Some term</option>";
  </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.select-style {
  width: 240px;
  height: 26px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  &::after {
    /*content: "\f107";
        font-family: "icomoon";*/
    content: "V";
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 7px;
    top: 0;
  }
}

select {
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(199, 199, 199);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: transparent;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: "";
  &::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

I've looked into having JS open the drop down, but found out that doesn't work. I've even tried using `z-index` to see if that would help... but for some reason the icon gets hidden even though the select has a transparent background.

How can I make it so that the custom icon is visible over the select but does not block my select from being clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position:relative` and `z-index:1` to the select itself

https://jsfiddle.net/hbpqvkqL/

```
select {
  ...
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yopu can set the ::after to have z-index: -1;

```
.select-style {
width: 240px;
height: 26px;
border: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
position: relative;
&::after {
/*content: "\f107";
    font-family: "icomoon";*/
content: "V";
font-size: 18px;
position: absolute;
right: 7px;
top: 0;
z-index: -1;
 }
}
```

Comment: This is what I tried and it didn't work on my page... however when I put it in the fiddle its working there... not sure why there is  difference at this point.

Comment: @smerny make sure that you set the position to relative, z-index only works with relative, absolute and fixed

Comment: @smerny it's probably a background.  See in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/58vk33zs/2/.  The arrow is rendered below the background causing it to be "painted" over

Comment: idk what it is, this exact css (including transparent background) in my site will hide the icon: https://jsfiddle.net/58vk33zs/3/ ... I shouldn't worry about it because Joseph's solution is working for me... but it's just confusing. I'll give you a +1 cuz it should work.

Comment: If you try adding `z-index:2;` to `.select-style` in the fiddle joseph linked [jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/58vk33zs/2](http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/58vk33zs/2) it works again, but you still need the -1 on the ::after

Comment: Oh, of course... the reason it was disappearing when I put a negative z-index is because of the background for the section of the page, not the select itself. That's why I have to give the select a higher index instead of a lower one on the ::after